# Are rooms in socket.io deleted automatically after some time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

First i'm a node.js begginer. I have a chat app which i created with `socket.io` the concept is i make a single unique room after 2 users are paired. but want to know if is it necessary for me to delete the room after the 2 members leave or i just let it.

I don't even know if the rooms are taking storage and how much..

some one help me understand please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rooms are automatically created and deleted as users join and leave.

As for storage, socket.io doesn't use any storage during runtime, just memory. A single user or room shouldn't use any significant amount of memory.

Comment: and how can i delete a room ?

Comment: `io.in("room1").socketsLeave("room1");`

Comment: I was incorrect. After doing some digging I found that rooms are "created" and "deleted" automatically when a user joins a room or all users leave one.
*Rooms are not like namespaces*; a room isn't created or deleted by users but managed internally by socket.io.

Comment: aah so this mean if both users disconnected they will also automatically leave the room right?

Comment: Yes, though the room could still be joined by other users